# Swap Out Image Outside of select list pulldown onChange

Tags: jquery, wordpress, select, onchange

I have a select pulldown that is created from a list.  On select plus clicking go the form will redirect in a jump menu fashion.  The pulldown in question is actually a WordPress Main Menu but for these purposes, that might not matter.

```
<nav class="widget">
   <ul id="odm-13-widget" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-122" class="menu-item-122"><a href="http://www.ex1.com">English</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-120" class="menu-item-120"><a href="http://www.ex2.com/">United Kingdom</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item-123"><a href="http://www.ex3.com/">France</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

The jumpto works.  What is I need is a corresponding image to the left of the pulldown to change on onChange.

```
<div id="langflagcontainer"><img id="langflag" class="flags" src="flag_us.gif" /></div>
```

The flag starts out with flag_us.gif but when you select United Kingdom or menu-item-120 onChange it will change to flag_uk.gif.  The next option for France would be flag_fr.gif.

I have found examples on SO that use a select list with value and option but not a list with ul and li elements.

As mentioned, I am using the WordPress widget.  It is the Optimized Drowndown Menu and I am not sure I can add value attributes to the li's.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) to accomplish this

[Download](http://jquery.com/download/), or link:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) library into your page, then add this code just before your `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#odm-13-widget").parent("nav").onChange(function(){
        var country = $(this).val();
        switch(country){
            case 'English': country = "us"; break;
            case 'United Kingdom': country = "uk"; break;
            case 'France': country = "fr"; break;
        }
        $("#langflag").attr("src","flag_"+country+".gif");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am using a WordPress widget to implement the jump menu.  It is pulling a menu to populate.  I am not sure I can add a value to each li.  Any way to use the already existing id and class descriptors?

Comment: I forgot to mention I have jquery used on the page already as the base theme was bones html5.  It already has jQuery v1.8.3 loaded in the header.

Comment: does it matter that the li has a href inside of it?  Almost there, just trying to figure out why this isn't working.  Instead of the case being the text can we use the li class or something?  The menu items are unique as noted, in WordPress.

Comment: When an item is selected, does it obtain a new `class`, or is there a "selected" attribute added to the `<li`>?

Comment: Thanks.  The answer didn't work without some changes but you got me there.  I ended up using the URL changing the case and using     $("#odm-13-widget").change(function(){
  var country = $(this).val();